# Sql developer selects string with spaces between charactes when using join

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm selecting a table that has a join in it. the selected lines are String type. The problem is that the selected line has spaces in between every character.
If i select the data separately from the tables I'm joining the data prints out just fine.

```
select las."land_and_sale_place_name",  sdes."land_place_txt"
    FROM vw_migrate_storage_declaration@oldizdis sdes
    left join land_and_sale_places@oldizdis las on las."land_and_sale_place_id" = sdes."land_place_id"
```

returns : "U A B   ' T e s t S t r i n g '"

while say a separate select

```
select las."land_and_sale_place_name" from land_and_sale_places@oldizdis las;
```

gets the correct string: "UAB 'TestString'"

PS. I'm selecting the data from a linked MSSQL database and I'm working on SQL developer for oracle

Comment: It looks like your first select results in double-byte characters being treated as single bytes. Are the encodings of the two tables in your first select different?

Comment: Both are Lithuanian_CI_AS

Comment: Also to note it works perfectly fine on PL/SQL developer

Comment: Which version of SQL Developer are you seeing this in? And what are the data types of the two text columns? It isn't entirely clear if you're getting the spaces in both string or just the first one.

Comment: The join is performed by the Oracle dbms.  What is the character set of the Oracle db? It looks like Oracle doesn't handle the conversion from the remote character set to the local character set correctly.

Comment: oracle db character set AL32UTF8

Comment: Oracle SQL developer Version 4.1.1.19
the MSSQL strings are nvarchar type

Comment: You might need to [look at HS/NLS settings](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/ds_concepts.htm#ADMIN12140), but I'm not sure they'd explain why you see different behaviour for the single-table and two-table queries in the same session.